ImguiライブラリをSDL2,OpenGLの環境でビルドすると、エラーundefined reference to `SDL_main'の対処方法が知りたい
質問内容
提示コードですが、以下の状況でImguiを用いた場合ですが、エラーが発生してリンクエラーになります。これはなぜでしょうか？いろいろ調べたのですが原因がわかりません。
試したこと

提示サイトを参考にmain()関数の引数や引数名を変更して実験
提示コードの一番上に#defineを追加
Imguiライブラリをビルドから外すと実行でき、ウインドウが表示されます。
cmakeファイルのライブラリリンク部のSDL2関係の順序を適当に変えましたが、この順序が適切でした。

参考サイト：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830218/undefined-reference-to-sdl-main-in-mingw32
実行環境
OS: Windows 10
コンパイラ: g++ mingw
ビルドツール: cmake, ninja
利用ライブラリ: glew, opengl, imgui, SDL2
エラーコード
C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.c.obj):SDL_windows_ma:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

cmakeファイル　一部
# ライブラリのリンク
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "mingw32")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "SDL2main")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "SDL2")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "SDL2.dll")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "SDL2_image")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "SDL2_image.dll")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "box2d")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "glew32")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "glew32.dll")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "opengl32")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "freetype")

ソースコード
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>


#include "imgui.h"
#include "imgui_impl_sdl2.h"
#include "imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <imgui_impl_glfw.h>


// ウィンドウサイズ
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;

SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
SDL_GLContext context;



void initSDL(SDL_Window** window, SDL_GLContext* context) {
    // SDL初期化
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) 
    {
        std::cerr << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // OpenGLのバージョン設定 (4.5)
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    // ウィンドウ作成
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL 4.5 Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (*window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }

    // OpenGLコンテキスト作成
    *context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(*window);
    if (*context == nullptr) 
    {
        std::cerr << "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(*window);
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }

    // V-Syncを有効にする
    if (SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) < 0) 
    {
        std::cerr << "Warning: Unable to set VSync! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    // GLEWの初期化 (必ずOpenGLコンテキストの後に行う)
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        std::cerr << "GLEW Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow(*window);
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }

    // OpenGLのビューポート設定
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}

void handleEvents(bool& running) 
{
    SDL_Event e;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}

void render() 
{
    // 画面をクリア
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

/*
    // ここにOpenGLの描画コードを追加
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame();
    ImGui::NewFrame();
    
    // GUIコードを書く
    ImGui::Begin("Hello, ImGui!");
    ImGui::Text("This is an example window.");
    ImGui::End();
    
    ImGui::Render();
    glClearColor(0.45f, 0.55f, 0.60f, 1.00f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
 */   
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
// 描画
    glFlush();
}

void imgui()
{
    /*
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();

    ImGui_ImplSDL2_InitForOpenGL(window,context);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 450");
    */
}


//int main() 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    bool running = true;

    initSDL(&window, &context);

    imgui();

    // メインループ
    while (running) 
    {
        handleEvents(running);
   
        render();
  
    }

    // クリーンアップ
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

